# Serialization of Map.Entry changed while upgrading jackson from 2.2.2 to 2.7.7

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

**Serialization of Map.Entry**

Below is JSON with jackson 2.2.2 while returning map from controller(Spring MVC 4.0.2)

```
Object {key: 51454, value: "message"}
```

Below is JSON with jackson 2.7.7 (Spring MVC 4.3.1)

```
Object {51453: "message"}
```

Due to above change my js is breaking. I don't want to change js code, so how can i change json response.

## Edit

In Jackson Upgrade Serialization of Map.Entry changed as per [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-databind/issues/565)

Which is breaking my api.

Comment: And what's the code?

Answer (score 1):

Serialization of `Map` has not changed, so I don't think your problem statement is complete.

But serialization of `Map.Entry` did change to use more compact serialization, so perhaps you are explicitly dealing with `Map.Entry` values?
If so, there is no way to configure this except by custom serializer or using some other type. But it may make sense to use an actual POJO and not `Map.Entry`.

Comment: You are right serialization of Map.Entry has been changed and we have huge uses of key and value in js code. I'm trying to figure out how we can adopt this change.

Comment: May want to tackle upgrade in smaller steps in general. I think change in this case was in 2.5.0 (issue #565?), so first upgrading to 2.4.6 may make sense. Won't solve the specific problem, for which you may need custom serializer. But can help ensure there are no other problem areas.

Comment: My problem solved after writing custom serializer for Map.Entry.